# Is it possible to set data in CSS for JS to know certain media queries are applying?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Is there a way for your Javascript to know that a specific CSS media query is applying without duplicating the conditions of the media query in your Javascript? I'm thinking something like the HTML data attribute, but for CSS.

For instance:

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 94em) {
    .menu{
        -data-break: sidebar-open;
    }
}
```

JS

```
if( $('.menu').cssData('break') == 'sidebar-open' ){
     ...
}
```

I'm trying to have a drawer open on load if the window is at a certain width and a certain media query is applying.

I realize I can do this by using the width in the JS, but I'd like to find a way to do it without duplicating the width variable. I also know I could make the JS conditional on the CSS rules within the media query, but that wouldn't be useful in this circumstance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't a nice solution, what you could possibly do is set the content property for some target element.

```
@media ...
    #target {
        content: "sidebar-open";
    }
```

Since the element is not a `:before` or `:after`, the content will compute to `none` for rendering, but you can still read the value with Javascript:

```
$('#target').css('content'); //"sidebar-open"
```

Comment: I was about to post the same answer :D

Comment: Brilliant! This is going to be immensely helpful.

Comment: This is one of the more devious examples of exploiting the fact that `getComputedStyle()` doesn't actually return the computed style.